# Namespacing, sharing models, reusing controller in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember 1.10 application with api support for 2 models, Students and Parents, and basic CRUD setup for each model, as well as the ability to read and write messages to/from Students and Parents when visiting their respective /show pages.

I must create an Inbox in which the messages as well as all the other data on Students and Parents is available and must do so without the ability to change or add to the api (i.e. I can' create a Messages endpoint).

Basically, I need to keep the Student and Parent models and controllers as they are, but need to be able to access them from routes namespaced under the Inbox like so:

```
Students
  -inbox
  -index
  -edit
  -show
Parents
  -inbox
Inbox
  StudentInbox  <-- should use StudentsRoute and StudentsController
    -index
    -show
    -edit
  ParentInbox
    -index
    -show
    -edit
```

So that visiting /inbox/students/123 will be using the model defined in the StudentRoute and the actions and properties defined on the StudentController. The InboxStudentsShowRoute should similarly have access to the StudentsShowRoute and Controller.

Instead of copying and pasting the existing code from the Student and Parent routes and controllers, is there a way to proxy actions fired from templates under the Inbox namespace to the relevant models and controllers and maintain the ability to pass in params.

For example, passing in params like `?unread=true` while on the InboxStudentsShow route would pass these to the StudentsShowRoute and Controller (and bubble appropriately to it's parent route and controller) or editing a Student from student/inbox/123/edit template would work just as it does on the student/123/edit template?

New to Ember and know there has to be a better way to reuse existing code and proxy actions from a namespace. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go here with creating a `Mixin` which holds same code for Route and specify `controllerName`, `templateName` in `InboxStudentsShowRoute`. Then, you extend from this `Mixin` in both routes. Model, template, actions, properties will be the same.

> For example, passing in params like ?unread=true while on the
>   InboxStudentsShow route would pass these to the StudentsShowRoute and
>   Controller (and bubble appropriately to it's parent route and
>   controller)

I'm not sure what do you mean here by `pass these to the StudentsShowRoute and Controller`, but CONTROLLER properties changed in one route should remain the same in another route, because controllers are singletons in Ember. I don't know what do you mean by passing query param to another route, because if you transition to other part of your app you change URL and you can't have 2 urls at the same time, so how could query params be passed to another route?

In Ember 1.10 query params are defined in Controllers so I guess behaviour will remain the same.

Example of `InboxStudentsShowRoute`(move code from `StudentsShowRoute` to `StudentsShowMixin`, define controller and template name):

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import StudentsShowMixin from '../mixins/students-show';

export default Ember.Route.extend(StudentsShowMixin, {
  controllerName: 'students/show',
  templateName: 'students/show'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. What I mean by passing query params is that, since I want the actions performed on the template for InboxStudentsShow to be able to change and filter the model set in the StudentsShow, i want params such as `?unread=true` to filter based on what messages on the StudentShow model are unread. 

I really want to do exactly what I can do already in Students and StudentsShow routes--the only thing that will need to change is the template. I'll give your solution a shot today and let you know how it goes. I appreciate that it DRYs up the codebase.

Comment: I think you'd need `Ember.Service` to keep most important properties in two routes in sync when you change something. I'd be pretty clean approach.